# I cant install the Intel HAXM,the installer welcome screen not appear when i clicking it

Tags: android, haxm

Currently i using Android studio 2.1.3,is have no problem with that.The problem is when i run the emulator,it keep saying the intel HAXM not installed.So i click the direct link to install it.But no matter how many time i try,is just keep showing Intel HAXM not installed,as shown below: [image: show that intel HAXM not installed]

[image: The installed show that installed is done]

This show that the installed is done.
and the process is repeat over and over again.Keep saying the install is done,and showing it not installed

So i tried to go to BIOS setting to open,and there is no option for me to enable the Virtualization Technology.The screen shown as below:

[image: BIOS SCREEN,no option to enable Virtualization Technology]

I also update the latest BIOS from Acer website.This just simply doesnt help,still dont have option to enable it.

But I checked task manager it stated that Intel Virtualization Technology is enabled.As below: 
[image: Task manager show that Virtualization enabled/]

Therefore I download the standalone Intel HAXM ,at Intel website,after I clicking the installed,there are no welcome screen or setup screen coming out.Just a flash for a second of the setup window,and then disappear.

So please help let me know,what is the problem and what way I havent try??

Answer (score 0):

go to android sdk folder, then open the folder

```
sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

you will find an executable file named:

```
intelhaxm-android.exe
```

double click to run it manually, then try again.

if you did not find this folder that means you did not install HAXM successfully, or installed it in another SDK location.

now after installing it, you have to check if your PC supports Virtualization or not, you can do it by running command line prompt window to open the black command screen. then open another normal explorer window and go to sdk on your hard disk

```
sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

then drag and drop the following file inside black prompt line window

```
haxm_check.exe
```

click enter, you should see the following two lines:

```
VT support -- yes
NX support -- yes
```

now you are ready, right click on the following file then choose "run as administrator"

```
sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe
```

if it blinked and automaticlly closed, try to stop antivirus for a while then try to run it as admin again, the installation should start.
after finishing HAXM installation try to restart android studio, it should run without any problems.

Comment: I just open the android SDK folder,but inside there is just dont have Intel folder.Just have 2 folder android and google.what is this mean??

Comment: I try to installed it via Android SDK.it show Intel HAXM done successfully.But the emulator there still show Intel HAXM not installed,and this repeat and repeat again.

Comment: where did you install it? if you can not find sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager folder that means you have installed it in another SDK Location, check the path location from android studio from file_menu>Settings... then on the left pane click on "Appearance & Behaviour" then click on "System settings" then "Android Studio" it will display android SDK Location path used by android studio check it.

Comment: just now I installed it by unchecked the box "Intel HAXM",then i check it again in android studiod start page..it run and said installed successfully,then i go back and test run the apps,it showing,Intel HAXM not working also

Comment: sir i found the "Intel file",and click to the executional file..But the driver doesnt appear,just flash out and disappear.do you know what happen?I face this for the whole day already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123741/discussion-between-ken-and-eng-samer-t).

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to use emulator for testing your apps then [genymotion](http://genymotion.com/) could be a best alternative no need to bother with HAXM and is fast.

Comment: I installed Genymotion as well..But it cant run also

Comment: It show Virtualization engin not found,Genymotion and Virtual box is installed as well.Can you help?

Comment: make sure your VBox is latest version

Comment: so am I just install and click "RUN" in android studio,it will act as emulator?

Comment: you need to run emulator first

Comment: for that you have to add virtual device first and you may install genymotion plugin and set the location of genymotion where it was installed and use that plugin to start your emulator and it will be shown in the list of connected device.